# Создание телеграм бота на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-openai

Всем привет, создаю телеграмм бота с chatGPT на python, возникла проблема в коде. Вот сам код:

```
import telebot
import openai
from config import OpenAIKey
from config import TgKey

openai.api_key = OpenAIKey
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TgKey)

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, я твой маркетолог в телеграм')
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def talk(message):
    response = client.completions.create(
        model="text-davinci-003",
        promt=message.text,
        temperature=0.5,
        max_tokens=1000,
        top_p=1.0,
        frequency_penalty=0.5,
        presence_penalty=0.5
    )
    gpt_text = response['choices'][0]['text']
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, gpt_text)

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Ошибка возникает на 14 строке, звучит так:

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'client' is not defined
  File "C:\Users\lolke\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Project\main.py", line 14, in talk
    response = client.completions.create(
               ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\lolke\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Project\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

можете помочь пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Как и упоминал [Anton Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/579992/anton-petrov).
Отсутствует инициализация класса OpenAI(),
которому приcваивается имя client

```
openai.api_key = OpenAIKey
client = openai.OpenAI()
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TgKey)
```

Попробуйте этот код, должен работать.

Answer (score 0):

Он у тебя ругается, потому что переменная client не импортирована.